# Grails getErrorCount() returns more than 1 error, how to get the list of errors?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, groovy

I have this constraint for this field in grails:

```
businessNumber(matches: '([0-9A-Z]*9)RA([0-9A-Z]*4)', maxSize: 15)
```

I am putting maxSize constraint so that grails embed a maxlength attribute on the html views. I make a unit test for the constraints that looks like this:

```
void testBusinessNumberExceedMaxSize(){
        mockChildrenSpecialAllowancesForm.setBusinessNumber("F%G&Hy934F4G6H%55")
        assertFalse (mockChildrenSpecialAllowancesForm.validate())
        assertEquals ("maxSize",mockChildrenSpecialAllowancesForm.errors.businessNumber)
        assertEquals (2, mockChildrenSpecialAllowancesForm.errors.getErrorCount())
    }
```

Then, it generates this failure:

```
testBusinessNumberExceedMaxSize(com.ass.socialservicescm.ChildrenSpecialAllowancesTests)
|  org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<ma[xSize]> but was:<ma[tches]>
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:125)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:147)
    at com.ass.socialservicescm.ChildrenSpecialAllowancesTests.testBusinessNumberExceedMaxSize(ChildrenSpecialAllowancesTests.groovy:177)
```

I assume that it violates 2 constraints(because my error count is 2), one is maxSize and the other is matches. But how do i do an assertEquals for maxSize constraint?

note: I'm using grails 2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

I use this to parse all the validation exceptions into a String and then I do an assertEquals in the calling code and compare it to the result of this. Maybe there is an easier way but for now this works for me.

```
public static String getErrorString(errors) {
    StringBuffer errorMsg = new StringBuffer();
    errors.allErrors.each {
        if (it instanceof org.springframework.validation.FieldError) {
            if ((it.defaultMessage) == null) {
                errorMsg.append('Error-> ObjectName:' + it.getObjectName() + ' /Field:' + it.getField() + ' /RejectedValue:' + it.getRejectedValue() + ".\n");
            } else {
                errorMsg.append(doReplace((String) it.defaultMessage, it.arguments) + "\n");
            }
        }
    }
    return errorMsg.toString();
}

public static String doReplace(String error, Object[] arguments) {
    int index = 0;
    arguments.each {
        error = error.replace("{" + index + "}", it.toString());
        index++;
    }
    return error;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try

```
assert 'maxSize' in mockChildrenSpecialAllowancesForm.errors.getFieldErrors('businessNumber')*.code
```